# stellar docker image db init failing after entering password

Tags: blockchain, cryptocurrency, stellar

First time trying to run stellar docker image in persistence mode and receiving this error after entering & confirming new password:

```
  pq: password authentication failed for user "stellar"
```

### docker cmd

```
  docker run --rm -it -p "8000:8000" -v "/dev/stellar:/opt/stellar" --name stellar stellar/quickstart --testnet
```

I looked at trying to edit pg_hba.conf but I don't see the stellar user that has been configured.

Also, I verified the stellar-core.cfg has the correct db password as defined during setup.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue while I was using a password with special characters (too fancy for `sed` to process?). Then I recreated the `'/opt/stellar'` shared volume and used `stellarpasswd` as a New Postgresql Password. And it worked! :)

Another piece of info, maybe more important. I have also added user `stellar` to my host machine. When the default configurations get `rsync`ed to `'/opt/stellar'`, this might not have worked properly without that user on my host machine..